# How to avoid extra parameters in grails (GSP page to Controller)

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am new with grails. In my web application I have a hidden field

```
<g:hiddenField name="tags" id="tags" value=""></g:hiddenField>
```

value of this hidden field is setting on Submit.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="setTag()" value="Ask Question"/>
```

and setTag method is defined as :
    function setTag() {
      $("#tags").val(selectedTagList);
}

selectedTagList is a List of Ids.

when ever going to controller, if the value sending is 1,2,3
and in controller the value reach as [1,2,3, , ]

if it is a,b   then the value reach as [a,b, , ]
two extra parameters are receiving in controller.
How can i avoid this extra parameters. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've test your situation.
It's a quite strange. There is empty value in controller via getting **params** variable.
But, its normally with TextField.
So, I think the first step, you should try to remove empty value in the list via this statement :

```
def clean = list.findAll { item -> item != ''}
```

Comment: in the first line of JQuery, the value of selectedTagList is setting as blank. Each time this page loads, selectedTagList value will be initially empty. Then what to do next?

Comment: notEmpty() method is not available, but isEmpty() will work fine.

But the extra parameters are still there.

Comment: i have used this:
def clean = list.findAll { item -> item.notEmpty() }
but the list is not changing.
where can I get the cleaned list?